# How to clear WPF text box without updating its two-way bound source?

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `Customer` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In my `CustomerDetailsViewModel` class, I have a property of type `Customer`. In the XAML, each text box is bound to each property of the `Customer` exposed by the my view model. I use `TwoWay` binding along with the `PropertyChanged` as `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

Now I want to have a "Clear" button which will clear contents of all text boxes. Intent is to allow user to create a new Customer using another "Add" button. "Add" button must be enabled only when user enters the correct text. i.e. there should not be any validation errors.

How can I clear all text boxes **without updating the values of the bound properties** of the Customer instance which is currently shown on the GUI?

My solution:
One approach could be to create a new instance of the `Customer` with all properties (like Name, Address etc) set to empty string. But problem is that that the moment I create new instance user sees the Error Template on GUI because validation (like 'empty Name is not allowed') fails.

Comment: Have you tried UpdateSourceTrigger to lostfocus or remove the UpdateSourceTrigger property since its a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTrigger. Something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding={Binding Text, ElementName=txtTextBox1} Value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question the thing you should do is unbind the Customer object when you use the Clear command, eg. create a new Customer from the one binded to the Interface.
The validation error showing up is just intended.

EDIT: Why would you want to hide the validation errors if you want to use them to force the user to enter correct data?
I think its actually more user friendly to give the requirements before trying to save.